# Reference and Value confusion

Tags: java, reference

Hi I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) question on Stack overflow, and tried to do an example.

I had the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     int i = 5;
     Integer I = new Integer(5);

     increasePrimitive(i);
     increaseObject(I);

     System.out.println(i); //Prints 5 - correct
     System.out.println(I); //Still prints 5
     System.out.println(increaseObject2(I)); //Still prints 5

}

public static void increasePrimitive(int n){
     n++;
}

public static void increaseObject(Integer n){
     n++;
}

public static int increaseObject2(Integer n){
         return n++; 
}
```

Does the `increaseObject` print 5 because the value of reference is changing inside that function? Am I right?
I am confused why the `increasedObject2` prints 5 and not 6.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: did you mean to use  `increaseObject(I);`? (note the `I` instead of `i`)

Comment: Integer is immutable in Java.
Similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560176/java-is-integer-immutable

Comment: @Alexey, then what is happening with the `increaseObject` method in this case, considering that Integer is immutable?

Comment: You can change this way: n = n+1. Here is exactly the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208943/how-to-increment-a-class-integer-references-value-in-java-from-another-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `return n++;` where n is returned and then only incremented. It works as expected if you change it to `return ++n;` or `return n+1;`

But still what you are trying to test does not work with `Integer` because it is immutable. You should try with something like -

```
class MyInteger {
     public int value; //this is just for testing, usually it should be private

     public MyInteger(int value) {
         this.value = value;
     }
}
```

which is mutable.

Then you can pass around the reference to an instance of that class and mutate it (change the value of `value` in that instance) from the invoked method.

Change the method -

```
public static void increaseObject(MyInteger n){
     n.value++;
}
```

and call it -

```
MyInteger i = new MyInteger(5);    
increaseObject(i);
```

Comment: Ahh..sorry I completely overlooked the postfix ++ part. Sorry that was a stupid mistake.

Comment: @rgamber: No problem, it happens. :)

Answer (score 1):

In `increasedObject2()` function,

> return n++;

It is postfix. So after n = 5 has been return, it increases n value, i.e n=6.