# Pass by Ref Java. Integer ins't modified, Collection is modified, Why?

Tags: java, collections, integer, pass-by-reference

I've got two examples I don't understand

Java passes the value as a variable or passes by reference

Why in the `Ref` class the integer variable is not changed `(null)`?
Why in the `RefCol` class the collection variable is modified `col(1)`?

class Ref:

```
test(): entero: 5

inicio(): entero: null
```

class RefCol:

```
test(): col: [1]

inicio(): col: [1]
```

.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Vector;


public class Ref {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Ref ref = new Ref();
        ref.inicio();
    }

    public void inicio(){
        Integer entero = null;
        test(entero);
        System.out.println("inicio(): entero: " + entero);
    }

    public void test(Integer entero){
        entero = new Integer(5);
        System.out.println("test(): entero: " + entero);
    }

}





public class RefCol {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        RefCol ref = new RefCol();
        ref.inicio();
    }

    public void inicio(){
        Collection col = new Vector();
        test(col);
        System.out.println("inicio(): col: " + col);
    }

    public void test(Collection col){
        col.add( new Integer(1) );
        System.out.println("test(): col: " + col);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208943/how-to-increment-a-class-integer-references-value-in-java-from-another-method

Comment: is not duplicated. I compare Integer vs Collection... ¬¬

Comment: The question referenced holds the answer to your question. The concepts remain the same regardless of which type of object you use

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In short: primitive types and "Primitive wrappers (Integer, Long, Short, Double, Float, Character, Byte, Boolean)" can not be altered via reference.

Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object for Details

Comment: this is my favorite answer: D is what I needed to know. Thanks!!

Comment: Primitive types and "Primitive wrappers"... Are generally all classes final? I'm triying with StringBuffer(is final) and not change.

Comment: This is only half the story. Because these objects are immutable you are creating a new instance insteead of calling a method on them, and hence reassigning the objexct the variable is referencing. If you did col = new ArrayList() you would see the same behaviour

Comment: Actually this is NOT a valid answer. He's not trying to change an immutable object anywhere in his code.

Comment: Mutability has nothing to do with this question. Assigning a reference of any type will never affect the object referenced, no matter what kind of object. The only way to "mutate" an object pointed to by a reference is to call a method on the object, like he is doing with `add`. He is not doing that with the `Integer` (well, it happens that there are no methods on `Integer` that changes it; but that is besides the point), so that is why it is not the same.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a COPY of the REFERENCE to an object instance.

If you change the object directly. e.g. `col.add` it will change the underlying object.

If you change the object it is referencing. E.g. `new Integer()` it will only change the reference for the local variable.

Answer (score 3):

Not the same thing.

```
entero = new Integer(5);
```

changes the reference `entero`, while

```
col.add(new Integer(1));
```

changes the referenced object `col`.

Answer (score -4):

{
objects created here will be destroyed after the ending of brace's(})

}

Comment: Nope, what about `col.add(new Integer(1));`